# Android Push Notification Through API

Tags: php, android, api, onesignal

I am using one signal API For push notification. And I want to know how can I send button with value(Confirm = 1, Deny =0) so that I can post it from the notification screen. I am not able to send action button through API t the app. I want to post the value of the action button in the database. Please help 
This is my code.

```
function sendMessage(){

    $heading=array(
        "en" => 'TEST'
        );

    $content = array(
        "en" => 'TEST.'
        );

        $hashes_array = array();
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "1",
        "text" => "Confirm",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "0",
        "text" => "Deny",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));


    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-45b8-97d4-02982b59c14f",
        'include_player_ids' => array($GLOBALS['one_signal_id']),
        'data' => array("Status" => 200),
        'small_icon' => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TzYz9McRVy8fD_WnpKiCK5anw20So6eyPR9ti-LwTd_QIer8BpAg8cMkRoO4sUv2xCDw=w300-rw',
        'large_icon' => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TzYz9McRVy8fD_WnpKiCK5anw20So6eyPR9ti-LwTd_QIer8BpAg8cMkRoO4sUv2xCDw',

        'headings' => $heading,
        'contents' => $content,
        'web_buttons' => $hashes_array
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    // print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    // print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5NjktMjRkZWM0ZjFhMjZl'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}


$response = sendMessage();
```

Comment: wait, you're using PHP android-side or webserver-side?

Comment: WebServer side. the page is notification.php